# XQuery вывод текста 'return'

Tags: xml, group-by, return, xquery

Есть xml вида, подскажите как правильно написать запрос, а именно сам вывод return

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>First item</name>
        <group>1</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Second item</name>
        <group>1</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Third item</name>
        <group>2</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Fourth item</name>
        <group>1</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Fifth item</name>
        <group>2</group>
    </item>
</items>
```

Как мне через xquery вывести в следующем виде:

```
group:1
First item
Second item
Fourth item
group:2
Third item
Fifth item
```

т.е. сгруппировать по элементу group?
UPD: необходимо вывести текст, использую Saxon-HE

Comment: Чтобы изучить XQuery, вы можете попробовать использовать BaseX: https://basex.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так.

```
for $item in items/item
let $g := $item/group
group by $g
return  
(
    'group: ' || $g, 
    for $name in $item/name
    return $name/text()
)
```

Comment: Saxon-HE, либо есть возможность использовать пробный Saxon-EE

Comment: и необходимо получить plain text